# Sending DocuSign envelopes via API 3.0 is no longer triggering Reminders or Expired warnings

Tags: docusignapi

Our software has been integrated with DocuSign since 2007. We've never included the notification element and the company's using the integration have always been able to use the DocuSign Admin to control those Settings. For some reason it is no longer working. I'm using the Demo environment for my testing. Has there been a change at DocuSign?

Here is an example CreateAndSendEnvelope request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AccountId xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">7ee2da0d-256c-4f73-8e7d-cd1bf921b2c1</AccountId>
  <Documents xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Document>
      <ID>1067</ID>
      <Name>Test DocuSign Lead</Name>
      <PDFBytes>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</PDFBytes>
    </Document>
  </Documents>
  <Recipients xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Recipient>
      <ID>97461</ID>
      <UserName>Jane Clark</UserName>
      <Email>smcmillan@gmail.com</Email>
      <Type>Signer</Type>
      <AccessCode>6541</AccessCode>
      <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
    </Recipient>
  </Recipients>
  <Tabs xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1067</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>97461</RecipientID>
      <AnchorTabItem>
        <AnchorTabString>[SignHere]</AnchorTabString>
      </AnchorTabItem>
      <Type>SignHere</Type>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1067</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>97461</RecipientID>
      <AnchorTabItem>
        <AnchorTabString>[Date]</AnchorTabString>
      </AnchorTabItem>
      <Type>DateSigned</Type>
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
      <DocumentID>1067</DocumentID>
      <RecipientID>97461</RecipientID>
      <AnchorTabItem>
        <AnchorTabString>[BankName]</AnchorTabString>
      </AnchorTabItem>
      <Type>Custom</Type>
      <Name>Custom Bank Name</Name>
      <TabLabel>Custom Bank Label</TabLabel>
      <CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>
      <CustomTabWidth>200</CustomTabWidth>
      <CustomTabHeight>25</CustomTabHeight>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
  <Subject xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">CreditSoft - DocuSign</Subject>
  <EmailBlurb xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">Please click link to sign the document</EmailBlurb>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the account settings get changed? There is a default set at the account level.

In your testing, do you get the notifications?

The setting is via the Admin Tool: **Signing and Sending / Reminders and Expiration** In my demo account, it appears that the default for reminders and expiring warnings is `off`.

Admin tool screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I reviewed and updated the reminders last week before i began my testing but I don't get any and the documents are not expiring.  I've always had them off in my demo environment but I know our clients using the integration have used them but for some reason it stopped working for them.

Answer (score 0):

Update from DocuSign that a bit over a year ago they made Notification.UseAccountDefaults required. In testing I also had to set Notification.UseAccountDefaultsSpecified to be true as well. Once that was complete my envelopes showed the correction expiration and reminder Settings in the Demo account.

```
Dim Notification As Notification = New Notification
    Notification.UseAccountDefaults = True
    Notification.UseAccountDefaultsSpecified = True
    envelope.Notification = Notification
```